# SQL SUM of Totals from different tables in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Not sure if this is the best way to do this, but I'll try to give an example to explain what I am trying to accomplish. I have about 4 or 5 different tables that each contain a `TOTAL` field. One table contains a `CUSTOMER_ID` (each of the 4 or 5 other tables contain a foreign key that links their records to the parent `CUSTOMER` table).

I want to group by `CUSTOMER_ID` in one column in my query while each of the other columns contains the overall total for the respective table.

Does this make sense? I'm looking for the most efficient and properly designed query. It sounds like I would need sub-query rather than a bunch of left outer joins?

Comment: The best way to do this would be to include a sample of your table structures, data and then the final desired result.  It is much easier to try and solve a question with those details, then trying to solve a word problem.  Right now, we would be guessing at all of these things trying to solve your problem.

Comment: subquery, join, cross apply, any would work. What have you tried, what is the actual problem you're running into?

Comment: I would suggest to just use the cte - common table expression - and than join like you want.

Comment: `SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(WORKORDER_LINE_ITEM.WORKORDER_LINE_ITEM_TOTAL), SUM(PROPOSAL_ITEM.PROPOSAL_ITEM_TOTAL)
FROM   CUSTOMER LEFT OUTER JOIN
       WORKORDER ON CUSTOMER_ID = WORKORDER_CUSTOMER_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    WORKORDER_LINE_ITEM ON WORKORDER_ID = WORKORDER_LINE_ITEM_WORKORDER_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    PROPOSAL ON CUSTOMER_ID = PROPOSAL_CUSTOMER_ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
    PROPOSAL_LINE_ITEM ON PROPOSAL_ID = PROPOSAL_LINE_ITEM_PROPOSAL_ID
GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID`

Comment: This is basically what I have. Sorry it didn't line up correctly. I want to group by `CUSTOMER_ID` and have two different columns that display the totals for that customer. First column would be for the `WORKORDER` line items and the second column would be for the `PROPOSAL` line items. My problem is that I think the way I am doing it is "double-counting". So if a customer has 3 items on a workorder, and 8 on a proposal, it ends up grouping 8 rows and duplicating the value on the workorder total if that makes sense.

Comment: @mntyguy that's exactly what's gonna happen. And that's why in my answer I group first and then do the join on unique `custome_id`s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  C.CUSTOMER_ID,
        T1.TOTAL TOTAL_T1,
        T2.TOTAL TOTAL_T2,
        T3.TOTAL TOTAL_T3,
        T4.TOTAL TOTAL_T4,
        T5.TOTAL TOTAL_T5
FROM CUSTOMER C
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL)
            FROM TABLE1
            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID) T1
    ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T1.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL)
            FROM TABLE2
            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID) T2
    ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T2.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL)
            FROM TABLE3
            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID) T3
    ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T3.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL)
            FROM TABLE4
            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID) T4
    ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T4.CUSTOMER_ID
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, SUM(TOTAL) TOTAL)
            FROM TABLE5
            GROUP BY CUSTOMER_ID) T5
    ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T5.CUSTOMER_ID
```

Comment: I'll give this a try. I thought this would be the safest solution.

Comment: I have a follow up question here. This solution technically worked and I appreciate the help. I structured it with nested SQL statements and Left joins. My issue now is how slowly it is to run. I ended up with 8 left outer joins and it takes a little while to pull up the dataset. The reason I am using the same large query is due to this being a sales report. So it's pulling data from multiple different tables to report in one dataset. Just wondering if there are any better methods for a larger query.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if I get what correctly what you are asking but I think you can accomplish this with simple joins, for two tables

```
select table1.customerId, sum(table1.total) as total1, sum(table2.total) as total2
FROM table1, table2
where table1.customerId=table2.customerId
group by table1.customerId;
```

and you can make it with as many tables as you want

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possibility.  It doesn't require deriving any tables then joining on them.  This should also be efficient enough, assuming that the FK on table1-table5 is the CUSTOMER_ID...Not 100% sure of that though.  Also in my experience when left joining, it's typically a good idea to use ISNULL so you always get some numeric value (although in this case it is another assumption on my part).  Hope this helps!

```
SELECT  
C.CUSTOMER_ID,
    ISNULL(SUM(T1.TOTAL), 0) AS TOTAL_T1,
    ISNULL(SUM(T2.TOTAL), 0) AS TOTAL_T2,
    ISNULL(SUM(T3.TOTAL), 0) AS TOTAL_T3,
    ISNULL(SUM(T4.TOTAL), 0) AS TOTAL_T4,
    ISNULL(SUM(T5.TOTAL), 0) AS TOTAL_T5
FROM CUSTOMER C
    LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T1.CUSTOMER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T2.CUSTOMER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TABLE3 T3 ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T3.CUSTOMER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TABLE4 T4 ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T4.CUSTOMER_ID
    LEFT JOIN TABLE5 T5 ON C.CUSTOMER_ID = T5.CUSTOMER_ID
GROUP BY C.CUSTOMER_ID
```